# Which symbol is used to represent an isometric isomorphism between two normed spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, banach-spaces

I've been looking for a symbol which could be used to represent an Isometric Isomorphism between two normed spaces. Reading many books or PDF's, I noticed that authors use different symbols for it such that:

$\longrightarrow{\sim}$ = \longrightarrow{\sim}

(the red symbol is not recognized by stackexchange.com)

$\overline{\approx}$ = \overline{\approx}

$\simeq$ =    \simeq

$\cong$ =   \cong

Does exist an agreement in the symbol for an Isometric Isomorphism?.

Comment: Your question contains its answer. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you've seen multiple symbols, then ask if there is a universal symbol?

Comment: I mean, when you see the symbol for an isomorphism it deppends in what area are you working, so it's difficult, at least for me, to understand what kind of operatios are preserving with that isomorphism if there's no clue about the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about  $\cong  $.  It seems to work in these types of situations...  or maybe ~.  I doubt there's much concern about this.   One would also quite likely just write $=$, when there's no confusion. ..

Comment: I tend to use "$X\approx Y$" for isomorphisms.  If I wanted to emphasize an isometry, I'd probably write "$X\approx_1 Y$".  It's not standard by any stretch of the imagination, but I think it's very readable and clear.  Just my 2c